# Gradient colour scale in ggsankey R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, sankey-diagram

I have a Sankey diagram in R using `ggsankey` and I would like to have a gradient colour that fills the flows. I create an example plot following [this](https://rpubs.com/oomiwale1/926103) example.

```
library(ggsankey)
library(tidyverse)

s1 <- sample(x= c("Single",
                      "Married", 
                      "Married with kids", 
                      "Married Without kids"), 
                  size = 100, 
                  replace=TRUE)
    
    s2 <- sample(x= c("Male", 
                      "Female"), 
                 size = 100, 
                 replace=TRUE)
    
    s3 <- sample(x= c("Happy", 
                      "Not Happy"), 
                 size = 100, 
                 replace=TRUE)
    
    d <- data.frame(cbind(s1,s2,s3))
    names(d) <- c('Relationship', 
                  'Gender', 
                  'Outcome')
    
    df <- d%>%
      make_long(Relationship, 
                Gender, 
                Outcome)
```

Then I create a custom vector of colors.

```
new_colors <- c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name = "Set3", n = 8))
new_colors <- setNames(new_colors, levels(as.factor(df$node)))
```

And I plot.

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x,                        
                     next_x = next_x,                                     
                     node = node,
                     next_node = next_node,        
                     fill = factor(node))) +
  
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5,          
              node.color = "black",     
              show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = new_colors)
```

[image]

For instance, I would like the colour of the filling to change from pink to violet as the flow goes from "single" to "male", and so on. I am trying with `scale_fill_gradient()` but I don't know how to specify `low =` and `high =` conditionally (i.e., based on the `node`).

Comment: There are no gradient fills of single polygons available in ggplot, although this feature will be available to extension developers in the next release (v 3.5.0). The `scale_fill_gradient` function does not perform a gradient fill, but rather maps the fill color of objects to a graduated scale. It would be possible to give the appearance of a graduated fill in the current ggplot version using hundreds of line segments, but this would require a fair bit of work to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, Allan, I thought as well that `scale_fill_gradient()` was not what I was searching for. Good to know this extension is being investigated.

Answer (score 2):

There are no gradient fills of single polygons available in ggplot, although this feature will be available to extension developers in the next release (v 3.5.0). The `scale_fill_gradient` function does not perform a gradient fill, but rather maps the fill color of objects to a graduated scale. It *is* possible to give the appearance of a graduated fill in the current ggplot version using hundreds of polygons but this requires a fair bit of work to achieve.

For example, this function will take a dataframe in the format of your dataframe `d` and create a sankey with a gradient fill using only `geom_rect`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

make_sankey <- function(
    dat, 
    colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name = "Set3", 
                                      n = length(unique(unlist(dat))))
    ) {
  
  sig <- function(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
    y1 + (y2 - y1) * pnorm(seq(x1, x2, len = 500), (x1 + x2)/2, (x2 - x1)/6)
  }
  
  df_c <- data.frame(var = levels(factor(unlist(dat))), color = colors)
  
  df_n <- do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) {
    gap <- nrow(dat) / 10
    table(dat[i]) |> 
      as.data.frame() |> 
      cbind(xpos = i) |>
      setNames(c("Var", "Freq", "xpos")) |>
      within({
        ymin <- c(0, head(cumsum(Freq + gap), -1))
        ymax <- cumsum(Freq + c(0, rep(gap, length(Freq) - 1)))
      }) |>
      within({
        ymin <- ymin - 0.5 * max(ymax)
        ymax <- ymax - 0.5 * max(ymax)
        xmin <- xpos - 0.05
        xmax <- xpos + 0.05
        xpos <- NULL
      })
  })) 
  
  df_f <- do.call("rbind", lapply(head(seq_along(dat), -1), function(i) {
    table(dat[[i]], dat[[i + 1]]) |> as.data.frame() 
    }))   |>
    left_join(df_c, by = c(Var1 = "var")) |>
    left_join(df_c, by = c(Var2 = "var"), 
                     suffix = c("_left", "_right")) |>
    left_join(select(df_n, -Freq, -ymax), by = c(Var1 = "Var")) |>
    left_join(select(df_n, -Freq, -ymax), by = c(Var2 = "Var"),
                     suffix = c("_left", "_right")) |>
    mutate(ymin_left = ymin_left + c(0, head(cumsum(Freq), -1)), 
           ymax_left = ymin_left + Freq, .by = Var1) |>
    mutate(ymin_right = ymin_right + c(0, head(cumsum(Freq), -1)), 
           ymax_right = ymin_right + Freq, .by = Var2) |>
    rowwise() |>
    reframe(color = colorRampPalette(c(color_left, color_right))(500),
            xmin = seq(xmax_left, xmin_right, length = 500) - 0.001,
            xmax = xmin + 0.002,
            ymin = sig(xmax_left, xmin_right, ymin_left, ymin_right),
            ymax = sig(xmax_left, xmin_right, ymax_left, ymax_right))
  
  df_n <- df_n |> left_join(df_c, by = c(Var = "var"))
  
  ggplot(df_f, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
    geom_rect(aes(fill = color), color = NA, alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
    geom_rect(data = df_n, aes(fill = color), color = "black") +
    scale_fill_identity(NULL, guide = guide_legend(),
                        labels = ~ df_c$var[match(.x, df_c$color)]) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(dat), labels = names(dat),
                       minor_breaks = NULL) 
}
```

Use is very straightforward:

```r
make_sankey(d) + theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

And we can see it will work on an arbitrary dataset of the correct structure:

```r
dat <- data.frame(A = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 200, TRUE), 
           b = sample(letters[1:3], 200, TRUE),
           C = as.character(sample(1:2, 200, TRUE)),
           d = as.character(sample(5:6, 200, TRUE)))

make_sankey(dat)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is impressive. It is probably a bit convoluted for what I want to achieve right now, but hopefully will be implemented later on. Thanks a lot for showing this!

Comment: @LT17 You're welcome. You can simply copy-paste the function. It should work on any appropriate data set.

Comment: @LT17 for example, see my addendum using a random data set.